# Adding deep nested object properties to Window in JS

Tags: javascript, object, window

I would like to clean up this block of code. Is there a way of setting deep object properties without using Lodash, Ramda or some horrible method that splits the object property string and loops through it?

```
export const initialiseBlackbox = (value = '') => {
    if (window === undefined) {
        window = { IGLOO }
    }

    if (window.IGLOO === undefined) {
        window.IGLOO = {}
    }    

    if (window.IGLOO.getBlackbox === undefined) {
        window.IGLOO.getBlackbox = () => ({ blackbox: value })
    }
}
```

Comment: `window.IGLOO = { getBlackbox: () => {} }` etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#using_object_initializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, but it's not pretty:

```
export const initialiseBlackbox = (value = '') =>
    Object.assign(window.IGLOO || (window.IGLOO = {}),
    { getBlackbox: () => ({ backbox: value }) });
```

Comment: Still prettier than using Lodash my guy!

Answer (score 0):

For a generic reusable function

```js
const deepSet = (t, p, ...v) => v.length > 1 ? (t[p] = t[p] || {}) && deepSet(t[p], ...v) : t[p] = v[0]
```

To use

```js
deepSet(window, "IGLOO", "getBlackbox", () => ({ blackbox: 'some value' }))
```